# Google Cloud Platformで独自ドメインを使用する方法

Tags: google-app-engine

Google Cloud Platform（契約済み） で独自ドメイン（取得済み）を使用する方法を教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

タグがGAEなんでGAEという前提でお答えしますね。GCEは普通のサーバと同じですから固定IPに対してDNSを割り振ればOKです。
GAEの場合は、CNAMEにghs.googlhosted.comという名前でgoogleに向けてあげて、GAEのプロジェクトの管理コンソール側からそのドメインを指定してあげればGAEのそのサービスに向けられるようになります。

細かい手順は公式サイトにありますので、以下を参考ください。
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl

以前はGoogleAppsが必須だったりしましたが、１，２年くらい前からドメイン設定は上記のようにGCPのみで出来るようになり、SSLもGCPで完結しだしたのが今年からですね。
なので古い解説日本語記事は役に立たないので現状これしか無いですね。